# Convert text to equation and return the sum result in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have text in the following format in `Column A` imported to another spreadsheet (impossible to add `=` manually because the data is imported automatically and change):

```
45+5
45+3
90+2
90+7
```

Is there any formula that can convert this text into an equation that gives the result of the sum in `Column B`?

For example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FUNCTIONTOCONVERTTEXTTOEQUATION(A1:A))
```

Expected Result:

```
50
48
92
97
```

Note: The texts will always be a number after the `+` sign and then another number.

Comment: Just put `=` in front of it so that sheets (and excel, and every other spreadsheet program in this style) knows it's a formula, not plain text?

Comment: It's imported data that changes automatically, there's no way to keep adding it manually.

Comment: [put that detail in your post](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is the sample data you provided in your post realistic? That is, are all of your equations additions of two numbers only? If so, then it would be simple enough to write a formula to do the math. If not, please explain in detail within your post the kinds of formulas that will be coming in (e.g., which operations might be included? will there be use of parenthetical hierarchy in the formulas? etc.).

Comment: Hi @ErikTyler The texts will always be a number after the ```+``` sign and then another number

Comment: Do you mean that the texts will always be a number BEFORE the `+` sign and then another number? If so, then this can likely be accomplished with one array formula instead of needing to do a drag-down formula. I'll await your reply.

Comment: Hello @ErikTyler , the values will always be like that are in the question.

Comment: See my posted solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your response to my clarifying question above, let's assume that your raw data is in A2:A. Place the following in the Row-2 cell (e.g., B2) of an otherwise empty column:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A,"+"))*1,0),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(A2:A,"+")),1,1,0))))`

`MMULT` is a powerful yet underused function. I'll include a graphic that explains what it does better than words might:

[image]

`SPLIT` will form the elements of the first matrix, while `SEQUENCE` will simply create the second matrix consisting of a column of 1's the same length as the number of horizontal elements formed by the `SPLIT` (which, in your case, will apparently always be 2).

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to see the quick update I made below the graphic for a bit more explanation.

Comment: I was just reading the explanation addition, thank you very much for that!

Answer (score 1):

Try, assuming the imported data starts at A1

```
=arrayformula(sum(value(split(A1,"+"))))
```

or, in a single formula at the top of the column

```
=mmult(arrayformula(value(split(A1:A4,"+"))),sequence(2,1,1,0))
```

Comment: Hello @MikeSteelson , unfortunately in this model when trying to use array it always sums all the values in a single result, the results must be each one in its proper row. Anyway thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: for that you will have to use MMULT, see my update